# LINQ equivalent of SQL NOT IN statement

Tags: c#, linq

I have a query that in T-SQL it is

```
SELECT *                         
  FROM rpm_scrty_rpm_usr ru                                         
WHERE ru.inact_ind = 'N'                       
  AND email_id IS NOT NULL
  AND wwid IS NULL
  AND LTRIM(RTRIM (email_id)) <> ''
  AND dflt_ste_id NOT IN (25,346,350,352,353,354,355,357,358,366,372,411)
```

When I have been converting it to LINQ, I have everything except the "NOT IN"

```
var querynonSystem = (from ru in Rpm_scrty_rpm_usrs
                where ru.Inact_ind == "N" && ru.Email_id != null && ru.Wwid == null && ru.Email_id.Trim() != ""
                && ru.Dflt_ste_id != 25
                select ru).Count();
```

I did temporarily put in this line  `&& ru.Dflt_ste_id != 25`

However I need to have `AND dflt_ste_id NOT IN (25,346,350,352,353,354,355,357,358,366,372,411)`

I am seeing a lot of different code like 
this lambda  `where !(list2.Any(item2 => item2.Email == item1.Email))`

Then `var otherObjects = context.ItemList.Where(x => !itemIds.Contains(x.Id));`

For my linq query, how can I do this `Not In` in simple manner?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use **Contains** with **!**. In addition, if you just want to count  rows, you can use **Count**.

```
var ids = new List<int> {25, 346, 350, 352, 353, 354, 355, 357, 358, 366, 372, 411};

var querynonSystem = XXXcontext.Rpm_scrty_rpm_usrs.Count(x => 
   x.Inact_ind == "N" &&
   x.Email_id != null &&
   x.Wwid == null &&
   x.Email_id.Trim() != "" &&
   !ids.Contains(x.Dflt_ste_id));
```

*From comment:* if you want to retrieve all, you can still use **Where** and **Select**.

```
var querynonSystem = XXXcontext.Rpm_scrty_rpm_usrs.Where(x => 
   x.Inact_ind == "N" &&
   x.Email_id != null &&
   x.Wwid == null &&
   x.Email_id.Trim() != "" &&
   !ids.Contains(x.Dflt_ste_id)).Select(x => x).ToList();
```

***FYI:*** you cannot call Rpm_scrty_rpm_usrs table class to query. Instead, you need DbContext or some other repository.

Comment: I might want to use  .ToList() as well FYI ,  most likely i will or neither and then create other filtering like `var querynonSystemCount = querynonSystem.Count();`

Comment: I do it in Linqpad first ,  which connects to sql server, then i put into visual studio   so   Rpm_scrty_rpm_usrs  = db.rpm_usr      ( db is the context , and rpm_usr is the property of dbset which is based on poco .... )

Comment: Awesome!     So also if I have another query in which I want to INCLUDE , instead of NOT IN ( ....)   I want    `IN( .... )      I would do same but  remove  `!` from the `!ids.Contains`  so that it is `ids.Contains`   right?

Comment: Correct. Contain for **IN** and !Contain for **NOT IN**

Comment: public int? dflt_ste_id { get; set; }    is causing a problem

Comment: : cannot convert from 'int?' to 'int'

Comment: `(x.Dflt_ste_id != null && !ids.Contains(x.Dflt_ste_id.Value))` OR `(x.Dflt_ste_id == null || !ids.Contains(x.Dflt_ste_id.Value))` depending you what you need.

Comment: Ok,  I'm trying      x.dflt_ste_id != null && !ids.Contains(x.dflt_ste_id.value)).Select(x => x);    but i get an error

Comment: 'System.Nullable<int>.value' is inaccessible due to its protection level

Comment: so does  `.value`  cause the problem ?     how about using  ??   how can that be used instead?

Comment: You can cast it. `(x.Dflt_ste_id != null && !ids.Contains((int)x.Dflt_ste_id))` OR `(x.Dflt_ste_id == null || !ids.Contains((int)x.Dflt_ste_id))`

Comment: Hey , I can create a new question , but I was trying to add a .Join  lamba above a .Where  and I get Anonymous Type error

Comment: `var queryAllUsers = Rpm_scrty_rpm_usrs      .Join(Rpm_scrty_emp_info, z => z.Wwid, ei => ei.Wwid, (z, ei) => new{z,ei})
    .Where(z => z.Inact_ind == "N" && z.Wwid != null)`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37487804/linq-to-sql-added-a-lambda-join-geting-anonymoustype1-does-not-contain-a-defi

Answer (score 0):

There is no "not in" operator unless the type of the query is the same as the type you want to filter against (in which case you could use except). Here it is not. You're working on an IEnumerable and you want to filter on it's ID so a list of int. The where with lambda and contains is your best bet and WILL be translated to an in on the SQL side by most providers.

```
var FilterIds = new List<int>{1,2,3,4,344,3423525};

var querynonSystem = (from ru in Rpm_scrty_rpm_usrs
            where ru.Inact_ind == "N" && ru.Email_id != null && ru.Wwid == null && ru.Email_id.Trim() != ""
            && ru.Dflt_ste_id != 25
            select ru)
            // Use this
            .Where(ru=>!FilterIds.Any(id=>ru.dflt_ste_id ==id))                
            // Or this
            .Where(ru=>!FilterIds.Contains(ru.dflt_ste_id))
            .Count();
```

Comment: .Where(ru=>!FilterIds.Contains(id=>ru.dflt_ste_id ==id))       ?

Comment: Cannot convert lambda expression to type 'int' because it is not a delegate type

Comment: @JeremyMiller Sorry either change contains with any or keep contains and only pass ru.dfit_ste_id to it not a lambda

Comment: @JeremyMiller Fixed my answer to illustrate it

Comment: Hey, how can i add a Join  ,  i'm getting error     .Join(Rpm_scrty_emp_info, z => z.Wwid, ei => ei.Wwid, (z, ei) => new{z,ei})
    .Where(z => z.Inact_ind == "N" && z.Wwid != null)

Comment: @JeremyMiller You need to ask another question about this, however note that if your base is well designed you never need to use join with linq, you should have navigation properties, so if you're the database designer and you're using .join you need to rethink this.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37487804/linq-to-sql-added-a-lambda-join-geting-anonymoustype1-does-not-contain-a-defi