# Linq to SQL added a Lambda .Join geting AnonymousType#1' does not contain a definition and no extension method

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, linq-to-sql, lambda

As join as I add in a Lambda .Join I am getting problem with my linq lambda `.Where(..`

```
 .Where(z => z.Inact_ind == "N" && z.Wwid != null)
```

That is fine UNTIL I add in `.Join` above it.

eg

```
.Join(Rpm_scrty_emp_info, z => z.Wwid, ei => ei.Wwid, (z, ei) => new{z,ei})
```

**linq query**

(Linqpad , so  Rpm_scrty_rpm_usrs is essentially the same as dbcontext dbset)

```
var queryAllUsers = Rpm_scrty_rpm_usrs
            .Join(Rpm_scrty_emp_info, z => z.Wwid, ei => ei.Wwid, (z, ei) => new{z,ei})
            .Where(z => z.Inact_ind == "N" && z.Wwid != null)
            .AsEnumerable()
            .Select(z => new rpm_scrty_rpm_usr()
            {
                usr_id = z.Usr_id,
                usr_lnm = z.Usr_lnm,
                usr_pwd = z.Usr_pwd,
                usr_fnm = z.Usr_fnm,
                wwid = z.Wwid,
                apprvr_wwid = z.Apprvr_wwid,
                chg_dtm = z.Chg_dtm,
                chg_usr_id = z.Chg_usr_id,
                dflt_ste_id = z.Dflt_ste_id,
                cre_dtm = z.Cre_dtm,
                cre_usr_id = z.Cre_usr_id,
                lst_pwd_chg_dtm = z.Lst_pwd_chg_dtm,
                lst_accs_dtm = z.Lst_accs_dtm,
                email_id = z.Email_id,
                inact_ind = z.Inact_ind,
                salt = z.Salt,
                tel = z.Tel                 

                //});
            })
            .ToList();
```

**Poco class**

```
public class rpm_scrty_rpm_usr
{

    public string usr_id { get; set; }

    public string usr_fnm { get; set; }
    public string usr_lnm { get; set; }
    public string usr_pwd { get; set; }
    public string email_id { get; set; }
    public string wwid { get; set; }
    public string tel { get; set; }
    public int dflt_ste_id { get; set; }
    public DateTime? lst_pwd_chg_dtm { get; set; }
    public DateTime? lst_accs_dtm { get; set; }
    public string apprvr_wwid { get; set; }
    public string inact_ind { get; set; }
    public string cre_usr_id { get; set; }
    public DateTime? cre_dtm { get; set; }
    public string chg_usr_id { get; set; }
    public DateTime? chg_dtm { get; set; }
    public string salt { get; set; }


}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you return:

```
.Join(Rpm_scrty_emp_info, z => z.Wwid, ei => ei.Wwid, (z, ei) => new{z,ei})
```

You're essentially creating a new, anonymous type that has a property for each of the data sources you're trying to join. I suspect you are instead just wanting to return the z object. Try:

```
.Join(Rpm_scrty_emp_info, z => z.Wwid, ei => ei.Wwid, (z, ei) => z)
```

The returned object should then be of type z, meaning you can access it's properties in your .Where() clause (because it's strongly typed).

Comment: FYI,  this person asked basically the same question ,  you deserve the answer IMO ,   I would just create an answer for the guy here   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37470564/change-syntax-to-linq-to-sql-lambda-join/37472916#37472916

Comment: You're very welcome @JeremyMiller, glad that helped!

Comment: And thanks @TomStickel, I've just started out posting here so the recommendation is very much appreciated :)!

Comment: @user3485422    No problem.   I had noticed you had responded with a Join lambda that I realized make sense to me, so when the guy asking the question had another question about the Join, I realized that he tried me code and asked another question...  and you certainly got it right for him.   So people on StackOverflow are really nice and helpful , the most annoying thing is snarky responses by people and then getting voted down with no comment etc...    as if your question or answer is so bad ...  :/

Answer (score 0):

After the join, each entry in the joined query has two `rpm_scrty_rpm_usr`s, one named `z` and the other named `ei`.

You need to clarify to the where statement: which one you want to filter on, for instance:

```
.Where(z => z.z.Inact_ind == "N" && z.z.Wwid != null)
```

Comment: As mentioned by @user3485422, one of your options is to only return z instead of an anonymous type with the two properties.

Comment: Great point! Returning the anonymous type will also give you the flexibility to access the "ei" object. This might prove useful if you need to add additional conditions to the where clause in future.